# Python merge list intervals

Tags: python

I have started to practice questions on leetcode and being a beginner I am facing some minor issues with the approach. The task at hand is to merge all overlapping intervals.

```
Input: [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
Output: [[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
Explanation: Since intervals [1,3] and [2,6] overlaps, merge them into [1,6].
```

I know there are better approaches to solve this problem with much better time complexities but my aim here is to identify the flaw in my approach.

Here is what I have tried:

```
def merge(self, intervals: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if len(intervals) == 1:
            return intervals
        intervals = sorted(intervals)
        i = 0
        k = 0
        while i < len(intervals)-1:
            k = k + 1
            for j in range(i+1,len(intervals)):                
                if intervals[i][1] >= intervals[j][0]:
                    intervals[i] = [intervals[i][0],max(intervals[i][1],intervals[j][1])]
                    del intervals[j]
                    i = i + 1
                else:
                    intervals[i] = [intervals[j-1][0],intervals[j-1][1]]
                    i = j
                    break       

            print(intervals,k)            
        return intervals[:k+1]
```

I thing the point where I am struggling is the else statement where I update the list if no overlapping intervals is found. Any help in pointing out where I am wrong would be great.

Link to the problem if required : [Merge Intervals](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is

```
del intervals[j]
```

Modifying a container while iterating over it is generally a bad idea. It often results in skipped or duplicated values.

Consider the inner loop, when `i=0` and `j=1`:

```
  i=0   j=1 
[[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
```

The intervals overlap, so the if block is executed:

```
intervals[i] = [intervals[i][0],max(intervals[i][1],intervals[j][1])]
```

resulting in:

```
  i=0   j=1 
[[1,6],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
```

then

```
del intervals[j]
```

resulting in:

```
  i=0   j=1 
[[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
```

then:

```
i = i + 1
```

resulting in:

```
        i=j=1 
[[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
```

But now the for-loop increments `j`:

```
        i=1     j=2 
[[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
```

Notice how `j` skips over the interval `[8,10]`?

It is better to create a new list of the merger intervals. If you must do it in place, work backwards from the end of the list. That way, any indexes that are changed are ones that have already been processed.